# Why are the Welsh and the Irish called "Taffy" and "Paddy"?

Tags: etymology, pejorative-language

Why are the Welsh and the Irish called "[Taffy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/taffy)" and "[Paddy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paddy)"?

Where do these words come from? And why are they considered offensive?

Comment: Those are names that come from the Patron Saints of those countries. You can look it up easily enough.

Comment: _Are_ they considered offensive? How about 'Scouser', 'Geordie', 'Cockney' etc?

Comment: My experience is that offense is an individual matter. No terms mentioned would have to be offensive to some. Geordies seem proud of the name .

Answer (score 1):

[Paddy](https://www.irishcentral.com/opinion/others/is-the-term-paddys-day-offensive), short for Patric, became offensive only in recent decades probably because of its association with [Paddy Wagon](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/paddy-wagon), according to the following site:

> Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary (Tenth Edition, 1993) defines "Paddy" as "Irishman" and adds "often taken to be offensive."
>
> A slew of others, the article notes – The Ninth Edition (1986), the unabridged Merriam-Webster's Third New International Dictionary (1961), the Oxford English Dictionary (1905), the Dictionary of American English (1936) and the Dictionary of American Slang (1967) – mention nothing about “Paddy” being offensive, with ***the OED tracing “Paddy” back to the year 1790 and defining it as "Nickname for an Irishman” and “pet-form of Padraic or Patrick."***
>
> ***The word “Paddy” started being defined in dictionaries as offensive in the 1980s and 90s,***  the author explains. As for Paddy Wagon, “a look into the Dictionary of American Slang confirmed that [his] earlier assumption was right: ‘A police wagon used for taking arrested persons to jail. . . . Prob. from the association of there being many Irish policemen.’”

(www.irishcentral.com)

[Taffy](https://www.etymonline.com/word/taffy) characteristic name of a Welshman, c. 1700, from Teifi, Welsh form of Davy (David) appears to have derived its offensive connotation from the nursery rhyme  [Taffy was a Welshman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taffy_was_a_Welshman)

> "Taffy was a Welshman" is an English language nursery rhyme with anti-Welsh lyrics, which was popular in England between the eighteenth and twentieth centuries. It has a Roud Folk Song Index number of 19237.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: The Irish are proud of their [PADDYWAGONS](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=paddywagon&num=50&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=8BFPVbSbRK5OcM%252CAAAAAAAAAAABAM%252C_&usg=__ke7czgTEW3DoYG2m1SysVlQk-EM%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinh6vcwaHZAhWJPN8KHSh2CIwQuqIBCIYDMDY&biw=1366&bih=622#imgrc=g4tgaAqC5ncOFM:&spf=1518477580137)